# Reducing the number of Class objects to access embedded resources

Tags: actionscript-3, embed

I'm building a Flex project with a lot of embedded bitmaps and such. The usual method for getting to the bitmaps in Actionscript seems to be to do something like

```
   [Bindable] [Embed(source = '../lib/WhiteFencePost.png')]
    private static var clsObstacleFencePost : Class;
   var bitmap : BitmapAsset = new clsObstacleFencePost();
```

I've already got several dozen of these things, and I can easily see ending up with hundreds of them by the time the project's done. Is there some way that I can avoid creating a Class for every bitmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways... Pack all files into zip - embed zip - unpack with any zip library for actionscript, then Loader.loadBytes pic needed. Zip contents can be enumerated, so if you know what to do with files by name, you don't even need file list in application.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create an assets manager with static classes like this.

```
class AssetManager
{

    [Bindable]
    [Embed(source = '../lib/WhiteFencePost.png')]
    public static var WhiteFencePost:Class;

    [Bindable]
    [Embed(source = '../lib/BlackFencePost.png')]
    public static var BlackFencePost:Class;

}
```

Then you can use the images like this

```
myImage1.source = AssetManager.WhiteFencePost;
myImage2.source = AssetManager.WhiteFencePost;
myImage3.source = AssetManager.WhiteFencePost;    
myImage4.source = AssetManager.BlackFencePost;
```

**You do not need to define a new instance of the Class images that you want to use.**

Comment: any reason not to use const instead of var?

Comment: more convinient when you're sure it really'll be constant :) and it's said that consts require less system resources, but imho it's funny comparing to graphics resource consumption

Comment: you can use const aswell :) just a matter of choice I think.